# Hashing function for session

Tags: 8, sessions

I need to verify the users session of Drupal on a Node.js server. The session ID has been hashed and it is stored in the Drupal 8 database. How can I hash the browsers session ID to compare it with the one stored in the database?

Comment: Check out lib/Drupal/Core/Session/SessionHandler.php, specifically the read function.  It uses Drupal\Component\Utility\Crypt::hashBase64($sid).

Comment: Do you mean compare it with Node.js code? I am not sure you can.

Answer (score 1):

I see that no one has put up an answer for quite a while, so I will put it up here. This has been correctly answered by [RaisinBrainCrunch](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235208/hashing-function-for-session#comment288780_235208) above.

Drupal 8 hashes its session ID before it puts it in the database. The hash function used is `hashBase64($sid)` under `Drupal\Component\Utility\Crypt`.

Therefore, I am guessing you will have to write the same function in Node. This is the full function:

```
public static function hashBase64($data) {
  $hash = base64_encode(hash('sha256', $data, TRUE));
  // Modify the hash so it's safe to use in URLs.
  return str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], $hash);
}
```